# How to draw histogram without the vertical lines in common between bars?

Tags: r

`hist` generates a histogram with the vertical boundaries of bars plots. If I don't want to draw the vertical boundaries that are common between adjacent bars, is there a way to do so?

Comment: Just about every question seems to be asking how to do something that is difficult in base R but would be trivial in ggplot. Is there a particular reason you can't use it?

Comment: @rawr but that argument doesn't preserve the outline of the histogram (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retain the outline, it's pretty trivial to draw a polygon over the histogram:

```r
set.seed(1)
h <- hist(rnorm(50))
```

[image]

```
polygon(rep(h$breaks, each = 2), c(0, rep(h$counts, each = 2), 0), col = "gray")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First some reproducible data:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- rnorm(100, 15, 4)
```

The `border=` argument is documented on the manual page for `hist` (`?hist`):

```
hist(x, border="lightgray")
```

No border.
[image: Barplot]